# After Effects Script: Inherit multiple character styles from parent text to child

Tags: javascript, adobe, after-effects

I have an After Effects script that copies the style and text of a text layer to another text layer in a separate comp. This works great if the parent text layer only contains one style, but I need one that is half bold and half normal. Is there a way for the script to loop through each character in the parent and apply that style to the corresponding character in the child?

This is what I have now - I found it in this tutorial: https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2020/01/24/after-effects-2020-express-yourself-and-your-text.html#gs.zzpqgg

```
var parentText = comp("Precomp - People").layer("Single Title").text.sourceText;
var parentStyle = comp("Precomp - People").layer("Single Title").text.sourceText.style;
parentStyle.setText( parentText );
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research into this a while back and came to the conclusion that this is not possible in either a script or extension.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would have put this answer into a comment, but I don't have the rep yet.